# chown: invalid user: ‘nfsnobody’ in fedora 32 after install nfs

Tags: nfs

I am install nfs using this command in fedora 32:

```
sudo dnf install nfs-utils
```

and then I create a dir to export storage:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv infrastructure]$ cat /etc/exports
/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins *(rw,no_root_squash)
```

now I could mount this dir with root user like this:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o v3 192.168.31.2:/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins /mnt
```

now I want to make a step forward to make it it avaliable to any user from any ip(the client could mount nfs without using sudo), so I first try to chown of this folder:

```
chown 777 jenkins
```

and then I want to make this jenkins folder group and user to nfsnobody:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv infrastructure]$ chown -R nfsnobody jenkins
chown: invalid user: ‘nfsnobody’
```

and I do not find any nfsnobody content from `/etc/passwd`. what should I do to fix `invalid user: ‘nfsnobody’` problem? should nfs-util added it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Right now **nobody** used by default probably after RedHat/Centos versions 8

*You can simply use*

```
chown -R nobody jenkins
```

*Or*

Change it from /etc/idmapd.conf

```
[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nfsnobody
Nobody-Group = nfsnobody
```

To put the changes into effect restart the rpcidmapd service and remount the NFSv4 filesystem:

```
service rpcidmapd restart
mount -o remount /nfs/mnt/point
```

On Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, if the above settings have been applied and UID/GID’s are matched on server and client and users are still being mapped to nobody:nobody then a clearing of the idmapd cache may be required.

```
# nfsidmap -c
```